# How to preload image form array in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image-preloader

I have problem with preloading images.

```
for(y=0;slide_image.lenght;y++){
   for(x=0;slide_image[y].lenght;x++){
      var preload_image=new Image();
      preload_image.src=slide_image[y][x];}
}
```

When I do it only with `preload_image.src=slide_image[x]`; it works, but when i have these two it doesn't. Maybe it's JavaScript bug?

Here is `slide_image` array:

```
var slide_image = new Array();

slide_image = [
    ['1/1.png', '1/2.jpg', '1/3.jpg', '1/4.jpg', '1/5.png'],
    ['2/text_1.png', '2/1.jpg', '2/2.jpg', '2/3.jpg', '2/4.jpg', '2/5.jpg', '2/6.jpg', '2/7.jpg'],
    ['3/1.jpg', '3/2.jpg', '3/3.jpg', '3/4.jpg', '3/5.jpg', '3/6.jpg']
];
```

Firebug and Firefox debugger says nothing. I don't know why this won't work.

Comment: Please see my edits for the reason why I say [JSBeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/) is great for helping us to understand and fix your question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typo'd `length` and you are using for loops incorrectly.  The middle "argument" to the loop should be a conditional expression which will determine when your loop stops.

Rewriting `length` and looping until your loop counters are less than the array's length, you get:

```
for (y = 0; y < slide_image.length; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < slide_image[y].length; x++) {
        var preload_image = new Image();
        preload_image.src = slide_image[y][x];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for starters youve mistyped `Length`